# Android Room сохранение вложенных Entity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

Недавно начал разбираться с android разработкой.

Никак не могу понять как с помощью Room сохранить в БД вот такой объект:

```
@Entity(tableName = "test_class")
public class TestClass
{
    @Entity(tableName = "inner_one")
    public static class InnerClassOne
    {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        private long idInnerOne;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "field")
        private double field;

        // getters and setters
    }

    @Entity(tableName = "inner_two")
    public static class InnerClassTwo
    {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        private long idInnerTwo;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "str")
        private String str;

        // getters and setters
    }

    @Entity(tableName = "inner_tree")
    public static class InnerClassTree
    {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        private long idInnerTree;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "id_test_class")
        @ForeignKey(entity = TestClass.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "id_test_class",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
        long idTest;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "ser")
        private int ser;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "vid")
        private int vid;

        // getters and setters
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_one")
    @ForeignKey(entity = InnerClassOne.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "id_one",
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    private long idOne;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_two")
    @ForeignKey(entity = InnerClassTwo.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "id_two",
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    private long idTwo;


    private InnerClassOne innerOne;
    private InnerClassTwo innerTwo;
    private List<InnerClassTree> lst;

    // getters and setters

}
```

- Какие аннотации надо написать для полей innerOne, innerTwo и lst?
- И что прописать в Dao?

Comment: никак это не сделать и мне, например, трудно понять, зачем кому то могло бы понадобится это делать . Дело в том, что каждый @Entity - таблица, как вы себе предсталяете таблицу в таблице в формате SQL? Вам может [@Embedded классы](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/27-course/architecture-components/530-urok-6-room-entity.html)
 (раздел "вложенные объекты") нужны

Comment: @pavlofff нет, вложенные объекты не нужны, как раз таки нужно сохранить все Entity в свои таблицы. Пока в Dao прописал методы для сохранения каждой Entity, которые вызываю послндовательно

Comment: в SQL нет такой структуры, как таблица таблиц и то, что у вас в коде нельзя реализовать. Может вы лучше добавите в вопрос, какую именно задачу вам надо решить, а не ваше [неверное] представление о ее решении.

Comment: Да не нужна мне таблица таблиц. Нужно чтобы каждая Entity лежала в отдельной таблице, а в основной таблице (за которую отвечает Entity TestClass) лежали внешние ключи на записи всех вложенных Entity. Сделал это через отдельные методы в Dao, которые вызываю последовательно. Соответственно в Entity TestClass на поля вложенных Entity добавил аннотацию Ignore.

Comment: Пытаюсь сохранить в базу распарсенный JSON